# Set all values of an existing array to "magic numbers"

Tags: c++, arrays, magic-numbers

So I know that I can set each value of an array to a "magic number" (in this case a magic string) at the time of construction like;

```
string * myArray[] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
```

What would be useful is if I could declare my array;

```
string * myArray[100];
```

Then later (in an if statement) set its values;

```
myArray = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
```

(the actual array will contain ~30 magic strings, so I don't want to assign them all one at a time)

I understand that magic numbers (or magic strings) are not good. However the system I am working in is CERN's root, which is full of interesting eccentricities, and I would rather not to lose any more time searching for a neater approach. So in the interest of not letting [perfect become the enemy of the good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good) I am going to use magic numbers.

What's the quickest option here?

Edit; The accepted answer works great for c++11. If, like me, you don't have that option, here is a very-nasty-but-functional solution. (Programmers with sensibilities please shield your eyes.)

```
int numElements;
vector<char *> myArray;
if(someCondition){
  numElements = 3;
  string * tempArray[] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"}]
  for(int n = 0; n < numElements; n++){
    const char * element = (tempArray[n]);
    myArray.push_back(element);
  }
}else if(anoutherCondition){
//More stuff
}
```

Comment: why not use a vector<string>?

Comment: why pointers to strings

Comment: Could do, but does that help? We still cant set like `={"foo", "bar", "baz"}` I think?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @BaummitAugen thanks, fixed

Comment: @NathanOliver Loop over all the branches in a tree (by name)

Comment: That doesn't compile did you mean `std::string myArray[] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};`?

Comment: Then skip using an array and use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  It has a function called `push_back()` that you can use to add elements to it during run-time and it will automatically expand to handle as many elements as you need.

Comment: @Giorgi because that was working when I had only one option (didn't need the if statement) is it bad style?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes but then I have do them one at a time and I might as well do `myArray[n] = "foo"`

Comment: Please use `std::array` if you want a static array, or `std::vector` if you want a dynamic array. There's no use for raw arrays in C++ anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although built-in arrays do not allow aggregate assignments, `std::vector` lets you do this:

```
vector<string> data;
if (someCondition) {
    data = {"quick", "brown", "fox"};
} else {
    data = {"jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/KNSlLX)

This approach has several advantages:

- The syntax is compact and intuitive
- Assigned aggregates are allowed to have different length
- Resources allocated to `std::vector` are freed automatically.

Comment: I receive an error from this - its long though so its in the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Jekowl You need to compile as (at least) C++11.

Comment: @Jekowl This syntax is available in C++11 and C++14, so you may need to turn on a special flag in your compiler (assuming that your compiler supports C++11 or higher).

Comment: @zenith ah, that may not be possible.  I will leave this question open for a bit longer, to see if any alternatives are suggested, then accept this answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Can you use the ternary (?:) operator to replace the assignment with a construction?

Comment: @KABoissonneault Yes, but the syntax is a little different ([demo](http://ideone.com/7mh9w3)).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Alright, it doesn't seem worth it in that case since it's going to end up as an assignment anyway

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably mean an array of `std::string` rather than an array of `std::string*` like this:

```
std::string myArray[] = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
```

The way I would do this is to allow a `std::vector` to manage the array for me. That allows me to easily copy, move or swap new values in later:

```
std::vector<std::string> myVector = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};

myVector = {"wdd", "ghh", "yhh"};
```